# excluding zero values to print a figure

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to print a figure with:

```
df_weight = df.groupby(['city'])['weight'].mean()

ax3 = df_weight.plot()
ax3.set_title("Weight by City");
ax3.figure.savefig("WeightCity.png")
```

The problem is I have many zero values in the weight column, so the mean calculation is wrong.

I tried this to find "Weight" values >0 and worked

```
weightUse = df.loc[df['weight'] >0 ,'weight']
```

but I don't know how to use that info to print the figure. Any ideas?

Comment: Ideally, you should not be using 0 to indicate 'not measured'. Replace them with NaN using some variant of `df.replace(0, np.nan)`, then calculate the mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print directly to stdout, here's a way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

df.query("weight > 0").groupby(['city'])['weight'].mean().plot()
plt.title("plot title")
```